Error with recursion I cannot figure out. JAVA
In Java, I am working with recursion, and I am sure I have the base case messed up. I am using Eclipse and the error I get fills the console so that I cannot see with the relevant information.
This is my code:
public boolean smallestDifference(Node node, int subSum1, int subSum2) { //
    //int difference;
    //int test;
    node = headNode;
    boolean addSub1 = false;
    boolean addSub2 = false;

    if (node == null) {
        System.out.println("Smallest difference:");
        System.out.println(subSum1 - subSum2);

    }

    if (subSum1 <= subSum2) {
        return smallestDifference(node.next, subSum1 + node.value, subSum2);
    } else {
        return smallestDifference(node.next, subSum1, subSum2 + node.value);
    }
}

The call in the main method is:
    linkedList.smallestDifference(linkedList.headNode, 0,0);


Does that code even compile? For starters it should return a boolean, and I don't think it does. In fact the only booleans I see there are initialized once and never used again. Please provide a [mre] that reproduces the issue you're having.

What is that method supposed to compute?

You have no end point for your recursion. Somewhere in the code, you need to return a concrete value, not just another recursive call. So I'm betting the exception you're getting is a StackOverflowError

it is supposed to traverse the list and add to subSum1 or subSum2. after the list is traversed, the method prints the difference between the two.

Side note: I speculate that you may be trying to compute the smallest difference between the sums obtainable by partitioning the list into two parts and adding up the values in each part.  (That is a variation on a standard problem.) If so, then your approach does not work.  For example, consider the list 1, 1, 2.  Your approach will compute 2, but the correct answer (for the problem I described) is 0.

This ...

    node = headNode;


... is surely wrong.  It's unclear what purpose, if any, you imagined that would serve, but what it actually does is ensure that every invocation of the method ignores the argument received in its node parameter in favor of the object's headNode field.
This compounds the issue described by @FerryTo in their answer, for even if you put a return statement in the if (node == null) statement to make it a base case, each recursive invocation will consider headNode, whereas you presumably want each one to consider the successor of the one previously considered.  Probably you just want to remove that assignment.
Either of those issues would individually produce a non-terminating recursion, which explains the long stack trace, too.  When the recursion eventually exhausts the available stack space, the stack trace will be hundreds or even thousands of levels deep.

This was it! Thank you I don't know how I didn't realize that. each time the method was called it was just setting it back to the head but when I called it in the main I had already set it to the head.

Your recursion code does not contain a termination criteria. There should be some code return true/false before the bottom condition.
if (node == null) {
    System.out.println("Smallest difference:");
    System.out.println(subSum1 - subSum2);
    // You should return a boolean here to terminate the recursion
}

Your recursion didn't terminate therefore even node is null it still continue to execute the bottom condition. Thus causing infinite loop.
